# Control Integer Range of a Defined Variable Within While Loop

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, while-loop, integer

I am trying to control (via multiple `IF` statements) the integer range of a defined variable within a `while` loop in Linux.

**My Bash Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

pad=3
START=1
END=246
i=${START}

while [ ${i} -le ${END} ];
do

num=$(printf "%0*d\n" $pad ${i})

echo "${num}"

if [ ${num} -lt "36" ];
then
((i = i + 1))
fi

if [ ${num} -ge "36" ] && [ ${num} -le "192" ];
then
((i = i + 3))
fi

if [ ${num} -ge "192" ] && [ ${num} -le "246" ];
then
((i = i + 6))
fi

done

exit 0
```

**Expected Output:**

```
001
...
...
...
036
039
042
...
...
...
192
198
204
...
...
...
240
246
```

**Terminal Output:**

```
001
...
...
...
036
039
042
...
...
...
192
198
201
204
...
...
...
243
246
```

After the `IF` condition has been met, post-192 and pre-246, the `${num}` variable is still increasing by `3` instead of *increasing by `6`*.

Comment: if num is 192, shouldn't it increase by 9?

Comment: I don't get the output you show when I run your code.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `printf '%s\n' {1..36} {39..192..3} {198..246..6}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented, running that code does not produce that output.

Carefully think about what happens in the loop when `i == 192` -- you want to be using `elif`

I'd suggest this:

```sh
while (( i <= END )); do
    printf "%0*d\n" $pad ${i}

    if (( i < 36 )); then
        ((i += 1))
    elif (( 36 <= i && i < 192)); then
        ((i += 3))
    else
        ((i += 6))
    fi
done
```

or this

```sh
for (( i=START, incr=1; i <= END; i += incr )); do
    printf "%0*d\n" $pad ${i}
    (( i == 36 )) && incr=3
    (( i == 192)) && incr=6
done
```